# Linq to sql avoid where in

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a list of ids passed by some other part in my program. I need to perform a linq-to-sql query on the DB (to lookup some other data). I want to do it based on the ids that identify my items in scope.

If id list was small enough, I would use "contains" in the linq expression. But it isn't. The problem is that the resulting SQL uses a "where in (id1,id2...)" clause which is getting too large.

My question is: how could I avoid that?

Of course I don't want an in-memory query, that would be easy - I want to let the DB do the job for performane reasons :)

Update: An example linq:

```
//this is passed in my program from somewhere 
int[] myList = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4}; is a list of ids. 
//this linq-to-sql will end up in a "where in" clause
myDataTable.Where(a => myList.Contains(a.ID));
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a SQL query you want to avoid, and the SQL query you'd rather have instead?

Comment: How did you get that `IN` list? Could you re-formulate your query in terms of an inner join to something that produces the `id`s from your `IN` list?

Comment: I added an example now.

Comment: If you have over 2000 parameters, you might be much better inserting them into a table and joining with that table, instead of passing them all in your query.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek this was exactly my question - So I need two round trips, first inserting, then joining. Is there any neat way how to do it in linq-to-sql as a "one liner"?

Answer (score 0):

We use this extension:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereValueIn<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
        Expression<Func<T, long>> propertyAccessor, ICollection<long> valuesList)
    {
        return query.Where(PrepareContainsPredicate(propertyAccessor, valuesList));
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T1, T3>> Combine<T1, T2, T3>(
        Expression<Func<T1, T2>> first,
        Expression<Func<T2, T3>> second)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), @"param");

        var newFirst = new ReplaceVisitor(first.Parameters.First(), param).Visit(first.Body);
        var newSecond = new ReplaceVisitor(second.Parameters.First(), newFirst).Visit(second.Body);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T3>>(newSecond, param);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> PrepareContainsPredicate<T>(Expression<Func<T, long>> idAccessor, ICollection<long> entityIds)
    {
        if (entityIds.Count == 1)
        {
            var cardId = entityIds.First();
            return Combine(idAccessor, x => x == cardId);
        }
        if (entityIds.Count == 2)
        {
            var card1Id = entityIds.ElementAt(0);
            var card2Id = entityIds.ElementAt(1);
            return Combine(idAccessor, x => x == card1Id || x == card2Id);
        }
        if (entityIds.Count == 3)
        {
            var card1Id = entityIds.ElementAt(0);
            var card2Id = entityIds.ElementAt(1);
            var card3Id = entityIds.ElementAt(2);
            return Combine(idAccessor, x => x == card1Id || x == card2Id || x == card3Id);
        }

        return Combine(idAccessor, x => entityIds.Contains(x));
    }

    private sealed class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly Expression _from;
        private readonly Expression _to;

        public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
        {
            _from = from;
            _to = to;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            return node == _from ? _to : base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
```

And call this:

```
var ids = new long[] {1L, 2L};
var result = query.WhereValueIn(o => o.Id, ids);
```

So, if you have small collection, LINQ will generate code with `Id = 1 OR Id = 2`, other way it will generate `IN` statement

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I think multiple "or" clauses are not very different to a "where in" statement from DB side. You will still hit the limit of the either the max query size or 2100 parameters, won't you?